# When were portions of Aramaic Book of Daniel translated into Hebrew?

Tags: daniel, judaism

John Collins writes in his 3rd option: "The whole book [of Daniel] was written in Aramaic, with portions supplanted, for whatever reason, by their Hebrew translation."
Is it plausible to assume that, specifically Daniel 9, happened after 33 CE [death of Jesus] and before 68 CE [destruction of Qumran]?

Additional info : Let me try to explain better with some chronological shortcuts. Imperial Aramaic was imposed in late 6th century BCE, by Darius I, king of Persia, as the official language in the Achaemenid Empire [539–323 BC]. Before, during about 1000 years, the scriptures were written in Paleo-Hebrew. After the Babylonian exile in 587 BCE, ‘Late Biblical Hebrew' developed under Aramaic influence and was preserved throughout history as the main liturgical language. According to the Gemara [Talmud], Hebrew of this period was similar to Imperial Aramaic. Qumran Hebrew is a continuation of Late Biblical Hebrew. It is found in the Dead Sea Scrolls and dated from ca. 200 BCE to 70 CE. Qumran Hebrew seems to show its own dialectal features.
I start from the fact that the Book of Daniel was originally fully written in Imperial Aramaic and that LXX is the Greek translation of it. So, at some point in time, Aramaic texts such as Daniel 9, must have been translated into [Qumran] Hebrew.
In order to find out if that translation was ‘influenced’ by the events after 30 CE, I ask the community if there is data, info or anything else that shows that the Hebrew translation in DSS was made before CE or after 33 CE.

Comment: Welcome to BHSX.  Thanks for your question.  Please remember to take the tour (link below) to better understand how this site works.  Here we need a specific Bible passage to analyse which is not what this question is asking.  Are you asking about a theory about the origin of Daniel or the interpretation of Daniel 9?  It is very unclear.

Comment: Copies of the book of Daniel, in their present form have been found among the Dead Sea Scrolls dating from about 200 BC.

Comment: Thanks Dottard - Please see additional info in Summary: I am not asking to analyze a specific Bible passage. I am asking if someone has more facts about dating the Hebrew in the DSS.

Comment: You are confusing two things - Hebrew script and the Hebrew language.  Hebrew from works such as Torah (which predates the Chaldean influence) is still similar to post-exilic Hebrew of (say) Malachi; however, the script used was vastly different.  For a question to be accept here, it must have a specific Bible passage - that is what hermeneutics is about.

Comment: Thank you Dottard. I am not confusing anything at all. All my comments relate to Hebrew scriptures, to what is written. Since I have no specific Bible passage other than questions about pre-MT Bible sections Genesis 5 and the book of Daniel, I will leave this post. Roger